# Expanding OSX partition and deleting Windows paritition

Tags: snow-leopard, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have created a Windows partition with Bootcamp. Now I would like to get rid of this partition and attach the available space back to the primary Mac OS partition.

I have found various tutorials around the net, but most of them seem to be outdated. I am wondering what would be the correct procedure for Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open Boot Camp Assistant again and it will ask you if you want to restore the drive to one partition. Therefore deleting the boot camp partition.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I deleted the boot camp partition using disk utility and now cannot reclaim the space for my primary Lion partition.